# GNS3 and packet generator

Tags: networking, packet-sniffers

I'm using `GNS3` and I need to know how to use ostinato with it can any one tell me me how to connect a packet generator to my topology ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Bernhard's page on [Ostinato for GNS3](http://www.bernhard-ehlers.de/projects/ostinato4gns3/)